# Looking for title of an old sci fi anthology with stories about the end of the world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a paperback published in late 70's or early 80's.

I remember the cover had an awesome pic of the earth blowing up and people being flung into outer space. I think the title was something along the lines of Cataclysm!  or Disaster!  or something along those lines.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Answer (score 21):

How about [*Catastrophes!*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?6386), a 1981 paperback anthology edited by [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov), [Martin Harry Greenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_H._Greenberg), and [Charles G. Waugh](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?7778)?

[image]

Comment: Wow, "pathetic" doesn't mean what it used to.

Comment: @MiloP Depends on the type of [pathos](https://literarydevices.net/pathos/)  you're aiming for.